# Angular 7 + ngx-bootstrap 3.1.3

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular7, ngx-bootstrap-modal

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uc6czc) is a blank angular 7 project in stackblitz, in Angular 6 I used `constructor(private bsModalRef: BsModalRef)` so I  can pass values to my child popup component.

But when I update to angular 7, it said `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service'`.

In stackblitz, it asked me to install ngx-bootstrap but I already installed.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you imported the package module?

Comment: Yes. `import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';`.

Comment: You're injecting `BsModalRef` while you should be injecting `BsModalService`. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing is you need to change your import in `app.component.ts`
 from

> import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

to

> import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

then you will have to provide providers in `app.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ModalModule.forRoot(),
  BsDropdownModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [BsModalRef]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

working **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xx7qku)**

Comment: It works but why the doc said `from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';` and no probiders.

Comment: When ever you're using a service you need to provide them in provider otherwise angular won't be able to understand that it's a service

Answer (score 1):

Please

```js
import {BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service'
```

and inject the BsModalService as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template), you'll need to inject the `BsModalService` as a dependency. But you're injecting `BsModalRef`.

Here's the correct syntax:

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
...
modalRef: BsModalRef;
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
}
```

Here's a [**Working StackBlitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.